# How to merge the array values in foreach?

Tags: post-meta

I have tried to get the checkbox values from postmeta field but cant merge the array into single result

```
$get_info_contact =     get_post_meta( $result, 'wpcf-society-info-contact', true );

$combined = '';
                            foreach($get_info_contact as $contacts){
                                 foreach($contacts as $contact) {
                                     $combined .= 'and';
                                    $combined .= $contact;
                                }
                            }
                            
                            echo $combined;

    Output: 
    
andalcorandpresident

    Expected output:
    
   alcor and president
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$combined = '';

$k=0;
foreach($get_info_contact as $contacts){
    foreach($contacts as  $contact) {
        //$combined .= 'and';
        //if(in_array($key
        if($k==0){
            $combined .= ucfirst($contact);
        }else{
            $combined .= ' and '.ucfirst($contact);
        }
    }
    
    $k++;
}
```

output:

```
   alcor and president
```